# Default value in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am reading data from serialport.

1. My Textbox Should show a value of 9600 as a default baudrate for my
   Serialport when i run the program.
2. If I enter a new value (5200), it should replace the default value.
   Can someone help?

   ```
   `private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        serialPort1.Open();

   }  `
   ```

   [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWB5.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to set, the textBox's value or the serialPort's BaudRate?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to set the textBox' value.

Comment: Well in that case your value assignment is the wrong way around, you should be setting value of the textBox like this `textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(serialPort1.BaudRate);`

Comment: It's very strange that you can't enter new value to TextBox control. Is this TextBox property Enabled set to 'true'? Maybe you set property ReadOnly to 'true'?

Comment: First I want My textBox to display a value by default like textBox1.Text= "9600"; in the second step I will assign the textBox value to serialport.

Comment: ok, that's clear to me, but when you want to change default value to lower/higher?

Comment: when I run the program the default value should appear in the textbox. Then if I want to change it, I will erase it and type a new value in the textBox.

Comment: so you want to change COM port baudrate "on the fly"?

Comment: yes, I should have the option to change it. Could you please click on the Picture in the question below the given code:) maybe things will become more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience i can say you one thing - IT'S VERY DANGEROUS to do such things. You should close connection first and open it again with different baudrate, because your device may simply ignore your request, but system driver will not... Such operation may cause invalid characters in buffer and perform unexpected bahaviour. I've never done dynamic baudrate change in my apps, but it wouldn't be surprise for me if system locks your TextBox control somehow as a source of some connection settings and preserving changes this way.
Try to close connection and then change your TextBox value.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am really sorry, I misunderstood you. I mean I should have the option to  change textBox's Text when I run the program and not the COM Port baudrate. Textbox's text show a string value (9600) which I can later convert to int form and assign to SeriaPort's baudrate.

Comment: I understand now - you want set TextBox value before connection start. OK. Have you checked properries 'Enabled' and 'ReadOnly' as I mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks for showing great patience and pushing me in the right direction :) It worked finally :) thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark my answer as solution. Thanks.